# Data in Javascript Object Performance

Tags: javascript, facebook

The more proficient I become with javascript, the more performance aware I want to be. For example, I had autocomplete box that would hit the server every so often to try auto-complete the users request. Exactly how google and most websites are enhancing their search. Now my question is if I am querying the FB api for a list of friends and storing these in a javascript object ( +- 700 with their full name and userid), **how will this effect performance?** I cant imagine it would be worse than constantly hitting the server for the request. Storing this info locally and then querying seems much more proficient. **Where do I draw the line in storing information in a javascript object.**  I would like my server to as little as possible and have adopted the philopsophy on letting the client do 80% of the work and the server the remaining 20%. Obviously I want the client to experience a smooth application. How do the js ninjas test the performance of their application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient solution - in terms of reduced network latency - would be to retrieve the friend list, store it using something like the localStorage API, and update the list in the background every once in a while. Keeping a list of this size in memory really shouldn't affect page performance much if at all (although on mobile this may not be the case). If someone has thousands of friends then you *may* see a slow-down, especially when reading the data from localStorage, but still, I doubt it.

Deciding where to draw the line is harder; it depends on so many factors. TBH this is something you may only know once your product is released and your users can give you feedback on performance, allowing you to fine-tune. A/B testing can help a lot in this regard.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What would be the difference in storing it in localStorage as opposed to a js object. Is it mainly the one is stored in memory as opposed to the harddisk? Have not had a chance to explore the API properly since we have to create cross browser apps.

Comment: Well, the first time a user launches your app you'd fetch the list from FB, and write the data to disk using localStorage. From that point, each time the user visits the app, you can simply read the data from localStorage into a JS object rather than fetching from FB. With this model you could utilise localStorage for browsers that support it; older ones would simply fetch the list from FB on each app load.